# how to assign list of images to image attribute in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, image, datatable

I have list of images and want to assign them to image attribute to be displayed in a datatable. How can I do that?
The idea is I want to retrieve value from database and depend on that value I want to display images. for example; if the value=2, then display 2 images; if it=3, then display 3 images...

> I got this: can not implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Windows.Controls.Image for this statement: Project.team_members = HandCards;

This is my code:

### Project class

```
public class Projects
    {
        public string developer_name { get; set; }
        public  Image team_members { get; set; }
    }
```

### asmx

```
List<string> developerNames = new List<string>();
List<Image> HandCards = new List<Image>();

Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = new Uri("images/img.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
source.EndInit();
image.Source = source;

while (somthing)
{
  developerNames.Add((string)rdrDev["user_name"]);//value returned from DB
  HandCards.Add(image);
}

Project.developer_name = string.Join(", ", developerNames);//I want to do 
//something like this for the images. this statement put all developers 
//together seperated by ','; I want to do the same to the next statement but 
//don't know how to do it for image type
Project.team_members = HandCards;
```

### aspx

```
var datatableVariable = $('#projects-progress').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [
         { 'data': 'developer_name' },
         { 'data': 'team_member' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with asp in a while but for the first part of your question, you could follow a similar implementation as the one shown below:

**In HTML Markup/ASPX Page:**
Say you have three images viz.

```
<img src="~/Img1.jpg" runat="server" />
<img src="~/Img2.jpg" runat="server" />
<img src="~/Img3.jpg" runat="server" />
```

**In C# Code Behind:**

```
string filePath1 = "Img1.jpg"; //You'll do the same for the other two images
Image img1 = new Image(string filePath1);
Image img2 = new Image(string filePath2);
Image img3 = new Image(string filePath3);

List<Image> listOfImageCollection = new List<Image>();
listOfImageCollection.Add(img1);
listOfImageCollection.Add(img2);
listOfImageCollection.Add(img3);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach(Image imgs in listOfImageCollection)
{
    dt.DataSource = imgs;
    dt.DataBind();
}

string myConnectionString = "";
SqlConnection mySQLConnection;
SqlCommand mySQLCommand;
SqlDataReader mySQLDataReader;



myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringToTheDB"].ConnectionString;
                using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                {
                    mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureNameToGetValue", mySQLConnection);
                    mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    mySqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
                    mySqlParameter.ParameterName = "@Value";
                    mySqlParameter.Value = Value;
                    mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(mySqlParameter);
                    mySQLConnection.Open();
                    mySQLDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    //Create a class to hold your DB properties
                    ClassName classInstance = new ClassName();
                    while (mySQLDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        classInstance.Value = Convert.ToInt32(mySQLDataReader["DBColumnNameHoldingValue"]);                                           
                    }

                if(classInstance.Value == 1 && dt.Count == 1)
                {
                  //Display one Image then follow the same procedure for the other conditions
                }
             }
```